# When is $R \, A^{-1} \, R^t$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse-problems

In the context of a Gaussian model, I came across a matrix product $R \, A^{-1} \, R^t$ where $R$ is a $m \times n$ rectangular matrix and as implied $A$ is $n \times n$ and invertible.

On which properties of $R$ does the existence of $(R \, A^{-1} \, R^t)^{-1}$ depend?

Comment: Please share your thought so far :)

Comment: My idea was to use the rank: $\operatorname{rank} R \, A^{-1} \, R^t \leq \min(\operatorname{rank} R, \operatorname{rank} A) = \min(\operatorname{rank} R, n)$, so if $R$ does not have full rank or $m > n$, it cannot be invertible. That's not enough, though.

Comment: @user18921 I cannot see how this question is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if $m=n$ and $R$ is invertible, then $RA^{-1}R^T$ is invertible as well.

Second, if $A$ is in addition symmetric and positive definite on the range of $R$, then $RA^{-1}R^T$ is invertible if $R$ has rank $m$. Actually, in this case $RA^{-1}R^T$ is symmetric and positive definite as well.

This does not work without definiteness of $A$:
$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}, \quad
A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\  1 &0\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
RA^{-1}R^T = 0,
$$
which provides an example, where $R$ has full rank, but $RA^{-1}R^T$ is not 
invertible.

Comment: You might slightly relax the restrictions on $A$ by requiring  $A$ to be SPD on the range of $R^T$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I expected. Do you know a theorem from which the answer follows, or sketch a proof?