# Why is the volume of a parallelepiped equal to the square root of $\sqrt{det(AA^T)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is the $\sqrt{det(AA^T)}$ equal to the volume of a parallelepiped?

Is is somehow related to the fact that $det(A) = det(A^T)$?

EDIT: To clarify, the parallelepiped is spanned by the columns of A.

Comment: what paralleliliped are you talking about?

Comment: The product $AA^T$ is there to cater for the possibility that the rows of $A$ are "too long". Or IOW that we are talking about the area of a parallelogram in a higher dimensional space, the 3-volume of a parallelopiped in an $n$-dimensional space and so forth. If $A$ is a square matrix, then $|\det A|$ will give the area/volume/whatever just fine.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant  and the reference at the end in "Journal of Young Investigators"

Comment: @Blackeyes, as always, suggest you do the 2 by 2 case really, really carefully, using some examples with, say, integer entries for $A,$ and drawing careful pictures and finding the areas of the parallelograms, just by splitting up the picture into a bunch of right triangles I suppose.

Comment: @Bla, next two vectors in $\mathbb R^3,$ where you can find the area using the cross product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning

Comment: @mookid, see the edit.  That should clarify what parallelepiped I am talking about.

Comment: @WillJagy, I understand "The magnitude of the cross product can be interpreted as the positive area of the parallelogram having a and b as sides".  I just am failing to connect that to $\sqrt{det(AA^T)}$

Comment: @Bla, the important part of this is that you do some (relatively easy) examples.

Comment: @Blackeyes: here is the proof (for any $d$). It should not be the expected one...

Comment: I think I got it.  $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$.  Thus, $det(AA^T)=det(A)det(A^T)=(det(A))^2$.  Since $Vol(P)=|det(A)|$, $Vol(P)=\sqrt{det(AA^T)}$

Comment: I think you should edit the title, since right now, it seems you'd need to take the fourth root to get the volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the vectors corresponding to the parallelepiped edges by $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$. The volume is equal to the absolute value of the mixed product of these three vectors
$$\operatorname{Vol}(\mathcal P)=\left|\,\vec a\cdot\left(\vec b\times\vec c\right)\right|.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, the mixed product can be computed in cartesian coordinate system:
since 
$$\vec b\times \vec c= \left(b_yc_z-b_z c_y\right)\vec e_x+\left(b_zc_x-b_x c_z\right)\vec e_y+\left(b_xc_y-b_y c_x\right)\vec e_z,$$ 
we have
\begin{align}\vec a\cdot\left(\vec b\times\vec c\right)&=a_x\left(b_yc_z-b_z c_y\right)+a_y\left(b_zc_x-b_x c_z\right)+a_z\left(b_xc_y-b_y c_x\right)=\\&=
\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_x & b_x & c_x \\ a_y & b_y & c_y \\ a_z & b_z & c_z\end{array}\right)=\operatorname{det} A.
\end{align}

Comment: it does only work with $d=3$.

Comment: @mookid the question is about $d=3$.

Comment: yes, but the result works in any dimension.

Comment: @mookid in any dimension it is not a result, it is the definition of the volume.

Comment: the downvoter: care to explain?

Answer (score 6):

Let us define the area of a parallelogram as $\lVert a_1\rVert\lVert a_2\rVert\sin\theta$ and see that it equals $\lVert a_1\rVert\lVert a_2\rVert\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{\lVert a_1\rVert^2 \lVert a_2\rVert^2-\langle a_1, a_2\rangle^2}$. The expression under the square root is the determinant of the [Gramian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) $A^TA$, where $A=\big(a_1 \enspace  a_2\big)$.
The same expression $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$ with $A=\big( a_1\; a_2\; ...\;a_k\big)$ can be used to find/[define](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations#Areas_and_volumes) the volume of parallelepiped and k-[parallelotope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Parallelotope) in higher n-dimensional spaces. Note that while $A$ may not be a square matrix, $A^TA$ always is.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854180/determinant-of-a-non-square-matrix/1590994#1590994

Comment: alternatively, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4726047/73934

Answer (score 2):

Write $A= QR$ with $Q$ orthogonal and $R$ upper triangular, so that
$$
vol(A) = vol(R)
$$

Then, using the usual formula for the volume of the triangle, the volume of $R$ is the (absolute value of the) product of its diagonal values. Then:
$$
vol(R) = \prod_{i=1}^d |R_{ii}| = |\det R|
$$
Hence
$$
vol(A) = vol(R) = |\det R| = |\det A| = \sqrt{\det AA^T}
$$

Comment: Can I ask how you got that the volume is just the product of the diagonals?

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is not interesting except if $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix with $n<m$. Then $\det(AA^T)$ is the sum - over every choice of $n$ distinct columns $C_{i_j}$ of $A$ - of the squares of the volumes of the parallelepipeds spanned by the $C_{i_1},\cdots,C_{i_n}$.