# Ratio of area formed by transformed and original sides of a parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product

I am interested in finding the ratio of area formed by transformed and original sides of a parallelogram, given by:
$$\frac{\|Ma\times Mb\| }{\| a\times b \|}$$
$M$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $ a, b$ are vectors with 3 components each ($a,b$ are sides of the original parallelogram and $Ma, Mb$ are sides after transformation).  I was thinking of using the identity:
$$(M a)\times (M b)=\det(M) (M^{\rm T})^{-1}(a\times b)$$

which is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859836/cross-product-matrix-transformation-identity?rq=1) but its not working out. Is there any way to find this ratio?

**EDIT**

Motivation: we can write the ratio of volumes of parallelepipeds in terms of only $\det (M)$ i.e. $$\frac{\|Ma.(Mb\times Mc)\|}{\|a.(b\times c)\|}=\det(M)$$ so I was thinking whether a similar expression in terms of only $M$ was possible.

Comment: What exactly is not working out with the identity you mention?

Comment: From that identity, I can not find the ratio in terms of only M for a general a and b

Comment: As the linked posting indicates, when $M$ is invertible, $(Ma)\times(Mb) = \operatorname{cof}(M)(a\times b)$. Therefore you shouldn't expect that $\|(Ma)\times(Mb)\|/\|a\times b\|$ is a constant, unless $\operatorname{cof}(M)$ (and hence $M$) is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: @user1551 My $M$ is always invertible. Also see the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio in general doesn't just depend on $M$, it depends on $a$ and $b$ too.

For example, for $$M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, for $a = {\bf i}$, $b = {\bf j}$, the ratio is
$$\frac{||M{\bf i} \times M{\bf j}||}{{\bf i} \times {\bf j}} = \frac{||{\bf i} \times {\bf j}||}{||{\bf i} \times {\bf j}||} = 1 ,$$
but for $a = {\bf i}$, $b = {\bf k}$, the ratio is
$$\frac{||M{\bf i} \times M{\bf k}||}{{\bf i} \times {\bf j}} = \frac{||{\bf i} \times {\bf 0}||}{||{\bf i} \times {\bf j}||} = \frac{||\bf 0||}{||{\bf k}||} = \frac{0}{1} = 0 .$$

Of course, in the special case $M = \lambda I$, the ratio is $\lambda^2$, which *is* independent of $a, b$.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981238/why-is-the-volume-of-a-parallelepiped-equal-to-the-square-root-of-sqrtdetaa/982191#982191) the ratio can be written as $$\sqrt\frac{\det((MA)^TMA)}{\det(A^TA)}=\sqrt\frac{\det (A^T(M^TM)A)}{\det(A^TA)}$$ where $A=\pmatrix{a & b}$.