# Is every "weakly square" matrix either a $0$ matrix, or a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Call a matrix $A$ *weakly square* iff $\mathrm{det}(A^\top A) = \mathrm{det}(A A^\top)$. Then clearly,

- every square matrix is weakly square, and
- every zero matrix is weakly square.

> **Question.** Are these the only examples of weakly-square matrices?

*Remark.* I got the idea from Donald Reynolds answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854180/determinant-of-a-non-square-matrix/1590994#1590994).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-square matrix $A$ is weakly square if and only if neither $A$ nor $A^T$ has full rank, which is to say iff $\operatorname{rank}(A)<\min\{m,n\}$.

The key to this observation is to note that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)=
\operatorname{rank}(A)=
\operatorname{rank}(A^T)=
\operatorname{rank}(AA^T)
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I don't really get it: in particular, why does that chain of equalities hold, and why does it imply the statement under question?

Comment: A square matrix has non-zero determinant iff it's rank is less than its size. The equalities are sufficiently well known that you can look them up easily. For the first, one shows that $A^TAx=0\iff Ax=0$ by considering $x^TA^TAx$.